# Hide the menu with jquery does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

menu should hide or show depending on the size of the browser window, but in internet explorer is not working. I used this jquery, if anyone can tell me what it is poorly written ???

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if(viewport()<767){

    $('.buttonShow').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.slide-menu').stop().animate({marginLeft: '0'});
        $('.brand').stop().animate({marginRight: '0'});
        $(this).hide();
        $('.buttonHide').show();
        if(viewport()<383){
            $('.slide-menu').css('width','100%')
        }
    });

    $('.buttonHide').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.slide-menu').stop().animate({marginLeft: '-315'});
        /*$('.brand').stop().animate({marginRight: '-436'});*/
        $(this).hide();
        $('.buttonShow').show();
        $('.slide-menu').css('width','368');
    });
  }

});
```

sorry if you did not understand, I hardly speak English

Greetings to all
zlyjoker102

Comment: Can you please show the code of `viewport()` function?

Comment: Does it work in Chrome, Firefox etc?

Answer (score 0):

Negative margins don't work in IE.
Use position:relative and left:-315

```
$('.slide-menu').stop().animate({left: '-315'});
$('.slide-menu').stop().animate({position: 'relative'});
```